# Invoke jsonStringify() outside Gatling EL

Tags: json, scala, gatling

Is it possible to invoke `jsonStringify()` to get a properly formatted JSON string outside a [Gatling EL](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/?highlight=jsonstringify)?

I need to convert a Map into its JSON String to calculate a signature.

```
val scn = scenario("My Scenario")
      .exec(buildPayload)
      .exec(http("Post")
          .post("/api/postSomething")
          .asJson
          .body(StringBody("${payload.jsonStringify()}"))

def buildPayload: Expression[Session] = session => {
  val header = Map(...)
  val data = Map(...)
  val signature = calculateSignature(JsonStringify(data)) // <<  is it possible??

  val payload = Map(
    "header" -> header,
    "data" -> data,
    "signature" -> signature
  )

  session.set("payload", payload)
}

def calculateSignature(payload: String): String = {
  ...
}
```

Do you see any other approach?

Comment: Maybe use `ujson`? Should be as simple as `import upickle.default._` and `write(payload)`.
http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/#GettingStarted